# Why Jenkins shows 404 if I open a URL with job path?

Tags: authentication, jenkins

I just set up Jenkins on a server and try to access it through http://{server_ip}:8080. If my access token expires, this will leads me to login page. However, if I try to open it with something like http://{server_ip}:8080/view/myjob, the page just shows 404 and I have to go back to http://{server_ip}:8080 first to trigger the login page. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's http://{server_ip}:8080/job/myjob with "job" not "view".

Comment: @smelm That doesn't matter, just an example. As long as there's any path, it shows 404 page.

Comment: So if you use a correct url this also happens?

Comment: Yes. I can open another tab and go to http://{server_ip}:8080 first to log in, then go back to my previous tab and refresh the page, everything goes perfect.